# How to test called promises not returned in tested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, promise, mocha.js

First of all, I've been trying almost everything to make this code work, and I achieved, the problem is that I don't like the approach, and I wanted to know if there was something better I could do in order to make the TEST code more readable, but functional.

**I want to assert** (with `sinon` for example) **that the second function (`secondApiCall`) has been called**, but it seems like there is no way to make that happen, how would you make it happen. Is it there a non hacky approach?

The main problem here is that "I can't modify the `functionToTest`" and I have to write tests that would be basically checking that the API calls are being done.

How with the given code would you run the assertions after `functionToTest` has finished?

PS: The code is shit, I know, but sometimes you just have to deal with it, you can't do more thank just test the shit out of it before refactoring it :(

```
const firstApiCall = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('firstApiCall success');
        }, 3);
    });
};

const secondApiCall = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('secondApiCall success');
        }, 3);
    });
};

const functionToTest = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        firstApiCall().then(result => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    secondApiCall()
                }, 2)
            })
    }, 15)
};
```

Basically the code that generates the mocks does something like this, so at the end you have synchronous code

```
const firstApiCall = () => {
    return {
        then: (cb) => {
            cb('firstApiCall success')
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `How with the given code would you run the assertions after functionToTest has finished?` - you can't because `functionToTest` neither returns anything, nor does it callback anything when it's done ... it's a poorly written asynchronous function

Comment: @JaromandaX I completely agree with you, I'm dealing with not very good code ATM, but somehow, and someone has to maintain it :( and the problem is that "you can't change something unless you can verify that there is no behaviour change" and that can only be done with testing (even if the testing is ugly and close to impossible)

Comment: You can't test this without changing the code. You say you can't, so don't test it. Not a good answer, but the only legit one. If the api call effects a stateful change you can poll to see if the change has taken effect in a promise loop and fail the test if it takes more than n milliseconds. That not great either but you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a couple of things, what you can always do, is mock the first API call, so at the end instead of an **async** call you would have a **sync** one thanks to callbacks, I will leave here an example, for whoever needs inspiration when testing promises that are not returned.

```
const firstApiCall = () => {
    return {
        then: (callback) => {
            callback('firstApiCall success');
        }
    }
};
```

PS: Once again, this solution is not the prettiest but it works at least.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check that the second API call did happen directly, unless the Promise is returned.

As described here:

```
const functionToTest = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    firstApiCall().then(result => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        secondApiCall()
      }, 2)
    })
  }, 15)
};
```

the Promise is not returned so there's nothing you can do about it IMHO.

Mocking the function is not useful here I'd say.

If you cannot test it directly, you can try to test it indirectly: even if it's pretty bad, you could check via the API the function is calling, that the state of the resource behind the API has changed as expected after the second call.
If you cannot test via the API well... there's no much to test then.